# How to display tabItem in foreground?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am using silverlight Tab control.There are three TabItems. When I selectsecond tab item it tucked behind the first and last. Whereas it should be displayed in the foreground. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to review your styles and templates of TabControl and TabItem, or if you can't find them in your code - they're defaulted, then try to specify your owns.

[Here is the link of TabControl ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137(VS.85).aspx)